# Okay to double up jwt tokens in http header?

Tags: javascript, http, express, jwt, fetch

I am using the jwt access and refresh token pattern. This means the client needs to send 2 jwt tokens in the header. Currently, I am just doing this:

```
'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + user.accessToken + ' ' + user.refreshToken
```

Then on my server, I split() the req authorization header and because I know that [1] is the access token and [2] is the refresh token I then have my tokens. Is there anything wrong with this method regarding security? I am newer to fetching/auth and know that there are specific practices to follow, and that this is probably breaking the normal use case of 'Bearer' but it works so I am want to use this solution if there aren't any security downsides. I am implementing authentication on my own and don't need to integrate with others so don't need Oauth2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I am using the jwt access and refresh token pattern.* I am sorry but that's not true. You make a token mixture which is unperformant, insecure and does not give you anything back in the end. And here is why.

The idea behind the **access token** is that third party services can use it in order to authorize the user.

The idea behind the **refresh token** is that user can issue a new pair of access / refresh token any time.

**What you do:**

1. you actually allow any third party to have both access and refresh token, which means if I'm a malicious third party I can use refresh token to keep user in my system (by getting my own access token and updating it all the time) and act on user's behalf forever
2. you attach a double-size token to the header, and JWT is well known for the size of the request headers. So you double the problem as long as normally the refresh token is nearly the same size as the access token
3. and you have nothing back. What is the win actually?

Comment: When you say 3rd party what do you mean? I'm only giving these tokens to my users. Not using Oauth or any social media login integration. And the point of the refresh token is that it lasts way longer and is stored in my database as well, so my users can reset password or I can suspend a user. This way they have the access token that is valid for 15 mins and means I don't have to check against the refresh token in the db but every 15 mins minimum which is much more performant correct? Also what is the problem with having a big header? Just slightly more bytes to send? Is that all?

Comment: 1. You should not check the user every 15 minutes because you have *access token* for that. The one that's given for 15 minutes. The purpose of the refresh token is to **refresh** the access token once a 15 minutes and normally this is implemented as a separate call because of the reasons above. 2. Sligtly more bytes means 0.15KB on every request for the smallest one from https://jwt.io/ and this is **something** especially for mobile network 3. of course you have the right to reinvent the wheel which is already invented and is far more advanced than the one you try to invent

Comment: https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt - this already does everything and is done by the people who know how to do that right

Comment: I wanted to use that package, but it doesn't support the refresh token approach correct?

Comment: at the moment you authenticate the user, you can issue 2 tokens: access and refresh. Then every time access token is about to expire (e.g. 5 minutes before it expires) you make a special call from the client to refresh the token where you pass refresh token only and get a new access token (and probably a new refresh token, depends on your needs). And that's it. Meanwhile you need to attach only the current access token to the request headers. That means you never send refresh token in the header, you store it like a username/password but safely on the client side

Comment: Okay, this is exactly what I need to do. This makes a lot more sense than my approach. Have read a ton on this and nowhere does it mention that so I came up with my own solution. Last thing. I will look into this, but what's the best way you know of to set a timer on the client to do a refresh token send 10 mins after an access token was received? Am I literally just creating a time that fires? If the user closes their laptop for an hour I want it to still fire when they get back on an hour later for example.

Comment: That's a good question and it has no defined answer. I normally start to attempt refreshing a quarter of the overall expiration time before it fully expires. If user closes the laptop and opens it later - no problem, if the refresh token is still valid, just get the new access token again and go on working. If refresh token is expired then show the login page again, that's all quite natural in the end of the day